# Enable/disable all monitors on keypress

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I want to disable/disconnect my monitors, GPU, or any other ideas to stop my PC from using the monitors its plugged into on key combo and re-enable it with a key combo. I thought doing it based on keypress made since so I could do it regardless of whether the monitors were disabled.

Ive seen an answer for specific intel GPUs but I have an NVIDIA Quadro K4000. Preferably I dont disable the card directly but I'm open to ideas.

The reason I want to do this is because I have processes I want to keep running in the background while I dedicate those monitors to my other PC.

Currently, both my computers pick up the monitors based on which computer is awake, but if I to keep the one I use for large downloads and personal use going, I have to physically disconnect the monitors and while not the worst thing in the world, its annoying because I have 3 monitors and the cords are in awkward places.

Im aware there are things out there like KVM switches, but I went this route because I had to return a very expensive KVM switch due to compatibility issues and so far, this has been the only issue with my current workaround.

Does anyone have an idea about how I could get my windows 10 PC to stop detecting the 3 monitors its connected to on key combo press (e.g alt+windows+5 etc) and start detecting the 3 monitors its connected to on key combo press?

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to disable/disconnect my monitors

You can use Nirsoft MultiMonitorTool:

> MultiMonitorTool is a small tool that allows you to do some actions related to working with multiple monitors. With MultiMonitorTool, you can disable/enable monitors, set the primary monitor, save and load the configuration of all monitors, and move windows from one monitor to another. You can do these actions from the user interface or from command-line, without displaying user interface.

Source: [Enable/disable/configure multiple monitors on Windows](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html)

Use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) assign keystrokes and run the command.

Comment: Thanks, ill look into it and see if it works for my setup later today.